# How to refer to exports function from inside Node.Js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, include

Supposed I have the following `exports` function inside `validate.js` of my Node.Js app:

```
exports.stopwordsClean = function () {
    return function(req, res, next){
        console.log("validating...");
    }
};
```

I understand that to refer to this function from another file I would first `require` this file and then use `validate.stopwordsClean()`

But how do I refer to it from inside the same file? `this.stopwordsClean()` doesn't work...

Comment: where do you want to use it? please post the code where you want to call `stopwardsClean()` method

Answer (score 0):

`exports` is an object which is available in `module`. When you write `exports.stopwordsClean = function () {..` you are setting a property `stopwordsClean` of `exports` object. Therefore you can always use

```
exports.stopwordsClean()
```

to use the function inside the same module.